# How to use value from forEach in building Record object

Tags: typescript

My implementation is like this

```
interface Data {
 [key:string]:string;
}
const array = ["a","b"];
const lines: Data[] = [];
array.forEach((key) => {
    lines.push({ key: "some text" });
});
```

After executing the code, the line array will have entries like [{"key":"some text"}] for example and not [{ "a": "some text"},{ "b": "some text"}]

How can I use value of actual key in building the line objects